# MySQL Count from one table, join to another table

Tags: mysql, join, count

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Table A has a record of user logins
Table B has the user's information

I want to computer the total number of logins for each user in table A, then join that to table B so my outcome is something like....

User 1    Name: John   Logged In: 15 times
User 2    Name: Mary   Logged In: 22 times

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need something like that:

```
SELECT u.*, count(l.id) AS login_count
FROM user s
LEFT JOIN login l ON u.id = l.user_id
GROUP login.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    COUNT(user_logins.user_id) as login_count
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN user_logins ON user_logins.user_id = users.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_id
```

If you don't need the users with 0 logins remove `LEFT` from the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: 2 or 3, I'm not sure. 1-st i added the LEFT/not LEFT advice and then i noticed i was missing `GROUP BY users.user_id`